# What is Steam's "download now" icon?

Tags: steam

In the Steam client application there is a *download now* icon, here it is with hover over:

[image]

and by itself:

[image]

What is this icon?

It kind of looks like this Chinese character 不 but it wouldn't really make any sense why that would be the icon for *download now*.

Comment: It is a download icon... There is nothing more to it.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid There's a bit more to it... See my answer.

Comment: @SaintWacko The question was primarily asking about the icon, not the function behind it, but your right, there is more to it :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The intent of the button is "Move to top of queue". It's an arrow pointing up, indicating that it's moving the selected item up, and terminating at a horizontal line which indicates the top bound of the queue.

Comment: is there a technical name?

Comment: It's nothing more than a descriptive graphic that's supposed to let you know that the current download will move to the top. It's not a *standard* or *universal* icon, it's just something that's supposed to intuitively make sense.

Comment: @user3306356 The icon used in the button similar to the character Unicode calls UPWARDS ARROW TO BAR (⤒), but my guess is that if Valve has given it a name it would be the "move to top of queue button".

Comment: @user3306356 I guess the technical name is "move-to-top" or "move-to-beginning"